# Resharper lost and cannot find my MSTestV2 unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper

For years, I have generated my C# unit tests from the VS menu (MsTestV2) and used ReSharper to run the generated unit tests.

The problem is that from time to time (several times a year in my experience), ReSharper loses the unit tests and cannot find them or run them. No circles show up in my VS text editor gutter.

I have tried things such as cleaning the solution, rebuilding it, rebooting Vstudio, deleting my .suo file, clearing the ReSharper Options>General>Clear Caches, deleting/restoring the test project reference to the tested project, adding a new test case manually to the test class, adding a new test class, and probably a few other methods that I cannot remember. None of them helped.

I have a small note from a past instance that tells me to copy all my test files, delete the entire test project, recreate it, add a new dummy test case, and when ReSharper can see the new test in the new project, cut and paste and copy my old test files into the new project.

Naturally, the MsTest runner in Visual Studio finds and runs all my tests properly.

The current test project and test cases have been working properly for many months, and I would rather not rebuild the entire project again. The only recent new thing in the past day or two is an upgrade to VS 16.7.0 and upgrade to the latest ReSharper Ultimate 2020.1.4 built on 2020-07-02. That might be the issue because ReSharper can't find the MsTestV2 tests on other projects too. It would certainly be an easy combination to blame. But my question is really about a reliable procedure for getting ReSharper to find unit tests that it has lost.

Does anyone know of a reliable way to get Resharper to find the current test projects and test cases again?

Comment: From [Not finding MSTest Unit Tests after upgrade to Visual Studio 16.7.0](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-480719) - _"This is known and was caused by API changes inside VS 16.7.0. It is fixed in the upcoming 2020.2"_

Comment: And the issue poster follows up with _"I've used the EAP and it appears to be fixed in that :"_

Comment: Excellent detective work on the Resharper issue tracker site. (I didn't even know that it existed and did not see it in a web search for the issue. I will watch for the Resharper update. Thank you!